# How to know when angular-busy's cg-busy is actively displaying (or how do I enforce a minDuration for a promise chain)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using angular-busy on an old angular 1.5.9 codebase (yeah, yeah, we're migrating soon, ...)

I am using it to do a "Check for updates ..." overlay and I want the busy message to show for a bit, so I set delay=0, minDuration=1500 just so it doesn't look like it flickers. The updates generally take < 200ms.

As part of the updates the content of what's in my $uibModal dialog updates and I'm using ng-show to hide it until my call has returned. That part works great. But because I'm using cg-busy's minDuration, the content shows before cg-busy's overlay has left - which I don't want.

cg-busy know's when it's active and not. Internally it uses a child scope for it's tracker class which has a method called $cgBusyIsActive() that it uses for it's own ng-show. It would great if I had access to that, but after researching a bit, alas, I can not find a way to get to it (and probably shouldn't even it I could).

> Question 1: Does anyone know of a way to detect when cg-busy is active and use that to ng-show or ng-hide?

Here's a quick snippet showing what I would like:

```
<div cg-busy="$ctrl.updatesBusy">
  <div ng-show="!$cgBusyIsActive() && $ctrl.updateResult.done">
    ...
   </div>
</div>
```

> Question 2: Or are there better/different ways of accomplishing my workaround below of forcing the promise chain to have a minDuration?

To get around this currently, I just create my own timer and shove a timeout in my promise chain that fires if there's any time left in minDuration, but I'd love a solution that uses cg-busy's minDuration.

```
const cgTimerStarted = Date.now();
$ctrl.updatesBusy.promise = myUpdateCallAsync()
    .then(function(result) { 
       // blah blah, blah blah
       return $q.resolve(); // return a promise obj or cg-busy will go away
    })
    .catch(function(err) { 
       // boo hoo, boo hoo
       return $q.resolve(); // return a promise obj or cg-busy will go away
    })
    .then(function() {
       const minDuration = $ctrl.updatesBusy.minDuration;
       const timeTaken = Date.now() - cgTimerStarted;
       const timeLeft = Math.max(minDuration - timeTaken, 0);
       return $timeout(timeLeft);
    })
    .finally(function() {
      $ctrl.updatesResult.done = true;
    });
```